# Typesetting smileys in the input

Tags: symbols, unicode, input-encodings

I'm inputting a file into LaTeX (in verbatim mode) that contains a unicode smiley character, code 128512.

I thought declaring

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{128512}{\smiley}
```

would do the trick, but:

```
Package inputenc Error: 128512 too large for Unicode.
```

Comment: `marvosym.sty` `tikzsymbols.sty` and `arev.sty` also having good smilies

Answer (score 21):

`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` takes the codepoint in hexadecimal notation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F600}{\smiley}
\begin{document}
Hello 
\end{document}
```

> [image]