# How to write many special characters such as ﷼₸₮₠₢₯ℳ₧™®?

Tags: font-encodings

I have a list of ~50 special characters that need to be included in my pdf. Latex won't compile with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} or with \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}. I can't find and write all characters one by one. Is there a way to write them and make the pdf compile?

My code is:

```latex
\begin{Code}
^[^\w°؋฿₿¢₡₵$₫֏€ƒ₲₾₴₭₺₼₥₦₱£﷼៛ރ₽₨௹₹৲૱₪₸₮₩¥₳₠₢₯₣₤₶ℳ₧₰₷©™®]
\end{Code}
```

where Code is

```latex
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Code}{BVerbatim}{baseline=t}
```

It compiles if the string doesn't contain special characters though so I think that the special characters are the problem

Comment: Please tell us which engine you're using as well as any packages you may be loading. E.g., which package defines the macro `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The biggest problem is to find fonts that have each of these glyphs. That done, you only need to get a way to access each. In XeTeX/LuaTeX you just need to load the font, and in pdfTeX you need `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512379/134574

Comment: @Mico i don't know if that's what your asking but I use pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX, and as for packages 
graphicx
listings
titling
float
titlesec
indentfirst
glossaries
[utf8x]{inputenc}
hyperref
makecell
fancyvrb
caption
fancyvrb

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik isn't there a way to import all of unicode like I would do for \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}? Cause that would be a lot of characters to declare...

Comment: @Mario `inputenc` allows for Unicode _input_, which you do have. But to have something written to the PDF you need a font with those characters, and no fonts (that I know of) have all of Unicode. The character declaration serves to tell LaTeX which characters to take from each font.

Comment: Unless you have a very specific need for pdfLaTeX here, you should definitely use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for this sort of thing. But as the others are saying, you need to find a font or fonts that contain the glyphs to begin with. But changing fonts inside a verbatim isn't possible so if you need more than one font, that's an additional hurdle.

Comment: For example, Noto Sans has one of the largest glyph coverages of any font I know, but it still yields 9 undefined characters when I compile the string in your code fragment.

Comment: And some of these glyphs appear to be Arabic script, which is an RTL language. Mixing script directions inside verbatim is also problematic.

Comment: I see, thanks all. I'll try to declare the characters